# Debugging an issue with COM object and RCW

Tags: c#, debugging

In my C# WinForms app I have a child app that is using a old VB 6.0 or maybe VC 6.0 ActiveX control as a text editor ( old ActiveX version of TXTextControl if you have used it).
In VS IDE when I close this child app that has this activeX control and then I close the main app and I get this error:

[image]

What are some techniques and ideas that you suggest for digigng into this and finding whats going on?  This does not happen if I run my app out side of VS IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities on how the COM object can be separated from the RCW, however I'm not sure why this would only happen in the VS debugger.

1. You must keep the reference to the ActiveX\RCW class. (Also, I've seen issues if you keep the reference as a static variable, so I'd recommend against keeping it in a static variable). For example: make sure `TXTextControl txControl = new TXTextControlClass();` that `txContol` holds the reference and is in-scope for the duration of the application
2. You might want to add manual clean up code, and possibly implement IDisposable on the class holding the RCW reference, before the Application closes or the Form hosting the AX control is disposed.
3. If you have attached any event handlers to the AX control, make sure they exit before closing the RCW reference and application. You might want to manually detach the handlers as well.